# How to send a variable from nodejs file to ejs file

Tags: html, node.js, express

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.use("/", function(request, response){
      var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("Test");
      dbo.collection("users").find({}, { "name":"John" }).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.ejs");

        db.close();
      });
    });
    });
    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="result"><%=result%></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have 2 files and I want to use a variable from one file in another. How can I send the variable `result` from my nodejs file to my ejs file, in `<h1 id="result"><%=result%></h1>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that you have to use express res.render()
according to the docs

> res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
>   Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Optional parameters:
>   locals, an object whose properties define local variables for the view.

You should use something like this

```
  res.render('index',{result});
```

then now you would be able to access that value you have sent over in your index.ejs file however I would advice you to **explicitly declare** in your application **that you are using ejs** so that you would **not** have to **go through the struggles of re-stating** ejs at the end of you code like before 
at the top after this code `var app = express()`
you could say

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Comment: if using `console.log(result);` i get an object like: `[ { _id: 5da4a1796f90a24d4f827878,
    name: 'John',
    email: 'test@mail.com',
    age: 1,
    hasCar: true,
    favColors: [ 'green', 'red' ] },

  {...} ]`, how to acces a specific value from an object and to output it in my ejs file? (for example, i want to acces name)

Comment: You could use dot notation like for example in your case in order to access the first array object  you could do `result[0]._id` or you could do this `dd[0]["_id"]` whichever is your preference

Comment: the issue is next: when i try to use `findOne` i get a result on front end, but when i try `dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {`  i didn't get anything on frontend.

Comment: I would advice you to open another issue since this one is resolved plus you could also use mongoose which is a simpler
 > Mongoose is an object data modeling (ODM) library that provides a rigorous modeling environment for your data, enforcing structure as needed while still maintaining the flexibility that makes MongoDB powerful.